# Clarification of MySQL index required to be "spanning" of all "and groups"

Tags: mysql, indexing

From the MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-btree-hash.html)

> Any index that does not span all AND levels in the WHERE clause is not used to optimize the query. In other words, to be able to use an index, a prefix of the index must be used in every AND group.

What exactly does this mean? Does it mean that for an index to be used, that every component of the AND query must refer to that index?

So lets say we have a `Person` table with `SID (primary)`, `first_name (index)`, `last_name`.

Does that mean that for the following query
`Select * from Person where first_name='foo' and last_name='bar'`
will not use the index on `first_name`?

Comment: Yeah, that sentence is pretty cryptic.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: The best index for your query would be 'composite': `INDEX(first_name, last_name)` - with the columns in either order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *`AND` group* is a set of comparisons that are combined with `AND`. A `WHERE` clause has multiple AND groups if it uses `OR` to combine several of these, e.g.

```
WHERE (col1 = 1 AND col2 = 2 AND col6 = 10) OR (col1 = '5' AND col4 = 'B' AND col2 = 16)
```

has two AND groups. There's one group that tests `col1`, `col2`, and `col6`, and another group that tests `col1`, `col4`, and `col2`.

So an index can be used if it has a prefix that's tested in every one of these groups. For instance, an index on `(col1, col2, col3)` could be used because the prefix `(col1, col2)` spans both groups.

Answer (score 1):

That statement in the document is rather misleading. It seems to contradict directly with the first example given [under that statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-btree-hash.html).

> The following WHERE clauses use indexes:
>
> ... WHERE index_part1=1 AND index_part2=2 AND other_column=3

Here it's clearly stated that the index is used even though other_column is not a part of the index. The confusion then, is caused by what exactly is an 'AND Group'. [Bamar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) has explained that really well in his answer so I will not go into that here. But suffice to say

```
Select * from Person where first_name='foo' and last_name='bar'
```

Will user an index provided that number of rows with first_name = 'foo' is much smaller than total number of rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you quoted here is referring to the multiple column indexing or compound indexes.

It indicates that if you have created an index on multiple columns, they all should be presented in the same order in and groups.

If you have crested an index on col1, col2, col3
And groups can be

```
col1=1 and col2=2 and col3=3
```

You can also have

```
col1=1 and col2=2
```

But you cannot have

```
col2=1 and col3=3
```

Because it is not the prefix of the index